# Handle memory management when dealing with complex data structures?

Tags: rust

I'm now developing and maintaining intricate data structures as part of a Rust project. My objective is to maximize memory utilization while avoiding frequent mistakes like memory leaks and overuse of memory. I'm still studying the best ways to manage memory with Rust, though, as I'm only recently familiar with the language. I'm searching for advice on how to manage memory in Rust when working with complicated data structures.

Here are some specific questions I have:

1. What are the best practices for managing memory in Rust when working with complex data structures?
2. How can I avoid memory leaks and excessive memory usage when using data structures like HashMaps, Vecs, and custom structs?
3. Are there any tools or libraries available in Rust that can help with memory management and profiling?
   How does Rust's ownership and borrowing system affect memory management when dealing with complex data structures?
4. What are some common mistakes or pitfalls to watch out for when managing memory in Rust?

I tried reading some documentation but i want to understand the best practice through experiments and learnings done by others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you create a new data structure, you are considered the owner of that. You can pass ownership to other functions or data structures, or borrow references to that memory. This ensures that memory is freed when it is no longer need it
2. Use data structures provided by Rust, Eg: `Vec::Vec`,`std::collections::HashMap`

Comment: Gee thanks! I have another question, what is the best way to enable debugging information?

Comment: You can use the `#[derive(Debug)]` attribute. This allows you to easily see data in the structure and how it is laid out in memory

Comment: @CtrlIntelligence `Debug` doesn't tell you anything about memory layout.